# What proportion of papers submitted to Nature are actually sent for review?

Tags: publications, journals

From Nature's "[Getting Published with Nature](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/get_published/)" guidelines:

> Nature has space to publish only 8% or so of the 200 papers submitted each week, hence its selection criteria are rigorous. Many submissions are declined without being sent for review.

This leads me to the question:

> **Question**: What proportion of the papers submitted to Nature actually get sent for review?

It'd be nice to know if, in general, the "biggest hurdle" in getting a paper published in Nature would be simply getting it to the reviewers.

Comment: Also, what are the reasons to reject a submission before reviewing?

Comment: @seteropere that is a completely different question, which you should ask separately!

Comment: @seteropere: I can't speak for Nature, but [this is ACM TISSEC's reviewing process](http://tissec.acm.org/content/process/reviewing-process-state-diagram/), a top journal in computer security. Basically, it can be rejected before reviewing for being off-topic, or if the substance is wrong.

Comment: Related, but does not directly answer your question: see [this post by Philip Ball](http://www.nature.com/news/rejection-improves-eventual-impact-of-manuscripts-1.11583) and the [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1227833) it is based on. (Also, [this one](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.200800513/abstract;jsessionid=AB42D03580A319E3EA47D70C563720E3.d02t02))

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Edited:** *I found a better answer to the question, the original indicative answer is left below.*

[Here](http://www.nature.com/nature/peerreview/debate/nature05535.html), we have a statement from December 2006 regarding the number of submissions, rate of editor rejections and ultimate acceptance number. While slightly outdated, the acceptance rate of *Nature* journal does not seem to fluctuate widely between 2006 and 2012 (always around 7-8% of submitted articles), hence I believe the number is significant and valid:

> *Nature* receives approximately 10,000 papers every year and **our editors reject about 60% of them without review**. ... ... In the end we publish about 7% of our submissions.

From that we have, that in 2006 about *40% of submissions were sent out for peer-review*.

---

**The original indicative answer:**
Not a precise answer, but can be indicative also for *Nature* journal itself: [here](http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v11/n9/full/nmat3424.html#/f1) is a statistics of a decade 2002-2012 of publishing in Nature Materials in numbers, various stats are presented. Specifically [this graph](http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v11/n9/fig_tab/nmat3424_F1.html) shows that the ratio of peer-reviewed vs. submitted manuscripts is floating around 13%. Out of peer-reviewed, about 60% get accepted. This shows that their first filter, the editorial decision whether to review at all, is extremely aggressive and in fact is *the* filter in the publishing process.

According to a note [here](http://network.nature.com/groups/askthenatureeditor/forum/topics/721?page=1), Nature Neuroscience sends about 30-35% papers for peer-review.

Comment: It would seem that the editor would have to be very familiar with you and the significance of your work ahead of time to get published in *Nature*.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones: I found an answer for *Nature* journal itself. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

These data are a bit more recent and specifically from *Nature Microbiology*, one of the newer NPG journals.

> We sent out slightly over 20% of submitted manuscripts for review and our acceptance rate was 9%. Of those 126 manuscripts accepted, 86% were published after 2 rounds of review or fewer, while 14% needed to be seen by at least 1 referee a third time.

noting this, it looks like the largest of the hurdles is indeed getting sent out for peer review.

source: https://www.nature.com/articles/nmicrobiol2016259

Comment: I don't really think a non-Nature journal from NPG really gives much insight into Nature itself.